# how to scroll down inside likers popup on Instagram?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

im trying to auto scroll down this popup [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L63ZM.png) but its not working well, my code should be wrong maybe. its not stop scrolling , i want it to stop for example at 20th user
this is the code i wrote :

```
for i in range(1,number_follower):
        src1 = self.wait_for_object(By.XPATH,f'/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div/div/span/a')
        self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",src1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

i also wrote this one two but still not work fine

```
        for i in range(1,number_follower):
        
        scr1 = self.wait_for_object(By.XPATH,f'/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div/div/span/a')
        self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", scr1)
        time.sleep(2)
```

and this is the full path to that popup:

```
/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div
```

i dont know how to use my for loop in the above xpath.

Answer (score 0):

find the scroll bar element and scroll that using scrollBy

```
scrollbar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector($('[class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        vwCYk                                                                            i0EQd                                   "] div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,350)", scrollbar)
```

or

This will scroll till the end

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)", scrollbar)
```

[image]